# ant propertyfile task update property removes all comments from the property file

Tags: java, ant

I am running ant version 1.6.5 on CentOS 5.5. I used ant propertyfile task (an optional ant task) to update some properties in a property file before loading the property file. The property file task seems to be removing all the existing comments from the file just leaving it with the property key-value pairs.

Here is my code snippet from the build.xml file:

```
<target name="version">
    <propertyfile file="${root.dir}/build/cbo_version.properties" >
        <entry key="major_number" value="${major_number}"/>
        <entry key="minor_number" value="${minor_number}"/>
        <entry key="maintenance_number" value="${maintenance_number}"/>
        <entry key="build_number" value="${build_number}"/>
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

Here is a snippet from my property file:

```
#
# This file was designed to contain basic information about a build/release such
# as its version, code label, etc. for the purpose of traceability.  
#
major_number=1
minor_number=0
maintenance_number=0
build_number=18
```

Once I build my application, all the lines in the property file prefixed  with "#" are deleted. I have tried the same code on mac os x 10.8.4 and with ant 1.8.2 and the code runs perfectly fine. I would like to have the comments left completely untouched by the propertyfile task. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited] Ant docu says about `PropertyFile` task:

*Since Ant 1.8.0 comments and layout of the original properties file are preserved.*

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html

Comment: isnot2bad - I need to update some properties before I load them. I will have to use propertyfile task.

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood your question completely. I've modified my answer.